# Angular - Load more items into list

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm new with Angular and I'm trying to do something like a **`loadMore`** or ShowMore button on my project, I'm stuck here so with u guys know something to help me I'll appreciate a lot.

I have a list with 10 elements, if my user has more than 10, we will have a `showMore` Button to click and load these other guys.

I'm trying to thing how to do this, but it's my first project and i'm confused about that.

```html
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="padding-top: 16px;">
<button (click)="showMore()" mat-button color="accent" style="width: 100%" value="bold">Show More</button>
</div>
```

```js
showMore(){

this.pageSize = this.pageIndex + 1;

this.get(10, this.pageIndex, 'Recents'); 
}
```

Until this moment i'm trying to change the current pageIndex and move to the next with the other elements. my Index starts is 0. and the 'Recents' is my reports Status to filter.

Comment: Share the code what you have tried with so far.

Comment: we need to see what you have done so far @Lulesi

Answer (score 1):

**Template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  msg{{item}}
</div>

<input type="button" (click)="LoadMore()" value="showMore">
```

**Component:**

```
currentIndex = 10;
items = [...Array(currentIndex).keys()];

constructor(private crd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

LoadMore(){
  currentIndex += 10;
  this.items = [...Array(currentIndex).keys()];
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but my list stop working by that way and i don't know why.
Console is not screaming anything.

Comment: You can manually trigger change detection or wrap inside setTimeout